# JQuery toggle Q&A: individual Q&As don't operate correctly unless you click on Open All/Close All first

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, toggle

I have a Q&A list with "Open All/Close All" at the top with individual open and close image buttons that toggle when clicked.  That works fine.

Then follow individual Q&As, and each has its own open and close image.

If you click on "Open All/Close All" first, as soon as the page loads, and then click on the individual Q&A open/close images, all works fine.  But if after page load you click on the individual Q&A open/close images, bypassing "Open All/Close All," they display the inappropriate open or close image.

Here is page code:

```
<div class="answersee"><span>Open All</span><img src="assets/open.gif" border="0" alt="" /></div>
<div class="answerhide"><span>Close All</span><img src="assets/close.gif" border="0" alt="" /></div>

<div class="qa">
    <div><img src="open.gif" border="0" alt="" /><span class="question">Question.</span></div>
    <div class="answer"><p>Answer.</p></div>
</div>
```

Here's the script (also uses Jquery):

```
$(function () {
    $(".qa").click(function () {
        $(this).find("div").next().slideToggle("fast");
        if ($(this).find("div:eq(0)").find("img").attr("src") == "open.gif") {
            $(this).find("div:eq(0)").find("img").attr("src", "close.gif");
        }
        else {
            $(this).find("div:eq(0)").find("img").attr("src", "open.gif");
        }
    });
    $(".answersee").click(function () {
        $(".answer").show("fast");
        $(".qa > div > img").attr("src", "close.gif");
        $(".answerhide").show();
        $(".answersee").hide();
    })
    $(".answerhide").click(function () {
        $(".answer").hide("fast");
        $(".qa > div > img").attr("src", "open.gif");
        $(".answersee").show();
        $(".answerhide").hide();
    })
});
```

I don't think it's a CSS problem, or I'd include that code here.  Do I need to initialize the script in some way?  Or did I make a mistake in the above script?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it.

[Working Demo →](http://jsbin.com/aquti)

**EDIT:**

Update the code to have simple open/close link.

Code with comments which explains my approach:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body
    {
        font-family: "Verdana";
        font-size: 12px;

    }
    .question
    {
        background-color: #ccc;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    }

    .answer {
        padding: 5px;
    }


</style>

<script>



    $(document).ready(
        function()
        {
            //Hide all the answers on page load.
            $('.answer').hide();

            //For all questions, add 'open'/'close' text.
            //You can replace it with an image if you like. 
            //This way, you don't need to specify img tag in your HTML for each question.
            $('.question')
                .append(' <span>[ open ]</span>');


            //Now there are two ways to toggle the visibility of answer.
            //Either click on the question OR click on Open All / Close All link.
            //To use the same code for both instances, we will create
            //a function which will take the 'question' div and toggle the answer for it.
            //Advantage of this approach is that the code to toggle the answer is in
            //one place.

            //By default, this function will try to toggle the status of the answer
            //i.e. if it's visible, hide it otherwise show it.
            //This function will take a second argument called 'showAnswer'.
            //If this argument is passed, it overrides the toggle behavior.
            //If 'showAnswer' is true, answer is shown.
            //If it's false, answer is hidden.
            //This second parameter will be used by the 'openAll', 'closeAll' links.
            var toggleAnswer = function toggleAnswer(question, showAnswer)
            {
                //The way I have structured the HTML, answer DIV is right after 
                //question DIV.
                var $answer = $(question).next('div');

                //Animation callback, after the animation is done, we want to 
                //switch the 'text' to display what could the user do with the question.
                //Once again, you can change this code to show open/close image.
                var updateText = function()
                                 {
                                    var text = $answer.is(':visible') ? ' [close] ' : ' [open] ';
                                    $(question).find('span').html(text);
                                 }

                var method = null;

                if(arguments.length > 1)
                {
                    //If the function was called with two arguments, use the second
                    //argument to decide whether to show or hide.
                    method = showAnswer === true ? 'show' : 'hide';
                }
                else
                {
                    //Second argument was not passed, simply toggle the answer.
                    method = $answer.is(':visible') ? 'hide' : 'show';
                }

                $answer[method]('fast', updateText);
            };

            //On each question click, toggle the answer. 
            //If you have noticed, I didn't enclose both Q&A inside one DIV.
            //The way you have done if user clicks on the answer, answer will collapse.
            //This may not be desirable as user may want to copy the answer
            //and he won't be able to.
            $('.question').click(function(){ toggleAnswer(this);});

            //We will reuse the same toggleAnswer method in openAll, closeAll 
            //handling. This way, if you want to change behavior of how the question/answers
            //are toggled, you can do it in one place.
            $('#openClose').click(
                function() 
                { 
                    var showAnswer = $(this).html().toLowerCase().indexOf('open') != -1 ? true : false;
                    $('.question').each(function() { toggleAnswer(this, showAnswer); });
                    $(this).html(showAnswer ? 'Close All' : 'Open All'); 
                    return false;
                } 
            );

        }
     );
</script>
<html>
<head>
<title>simple document</title>
</head>
<body>

<a id='openClose' href='#'>Open All</a>

<br /><br />

<div class='question'>Question 1</div>
<div class='answer'>Answer 1</div>

<div class='question'>Question 2</div>
<div class='answer'>Answer 2</div>

<div class='question'>Question 3</div>
<div class='answer'>Answer 3</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the callbacks because your animation will not have finished by the time to check for which image is being shown.

```
 $(".qa").click(function() {
    $(this).find("div").next().slideToggle("fast", toggleImage);
 }

 function toggleImage(){
    var $img = $(this).find("img");
    $img.attr('src') == "open.gif" ? $img.attr('src', "close.gif") : $img.attr('src', "open.gif");

 }
```

N.B There are better ways to do this but lets get you working first and then see if you want to refactor it some more.

Comment: Thank you for your help, though.  I'm not able to integrate your code successfully with the rest of mine.  I've tried various things.  Can you provide the entire script?  I know that's asking a lot, but I must be making a mistake in my syntax.

Comment: Sorry I read the Q wrong. its late. If nobody else helps I will do it when I wake up.

Comment: @redsquare - N.B instead of P.S? any chance you from Israel? ;-)

Comment: @Tom Teman nope I am uk based. NB sounds ok here - " to draw the attention of the reader to a certain (side) aspect or detail of the subject on hand"

Comment: @redsquare - heh, funny. In Hebrew the initials sound the same. And a quick Wikipedia search shows that the Hebrew initials are actually directly derived from the Latin NB (nota bene). Today I learned :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for taking the time to provide this.  I will try this later today and report back.  In my version, I toggle the Open All/Close All feature.  It's a cleaner look and easier to use, since you don't have to move your mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Redsquare and Solution Yogi:

Thanks.  I will reply again later and also post a working demo so you can see the problem more clearly.  Sorry, I should have done that before.

Liz

Comment: Liz, please make use of comments to post your comment to any particular answer. I also updated my code to use single 'open/close' link.